# Testing an inheriting C# class

Tags: c#, testing, nunit, fitnesse

I have the following code in c♯ but can not work out how to test it; I need to test aMethodUnderTest. I can not change ABaseClass as it is in a library. But if I am to test AClass I need to be able to set what theThing returns. Does anyone have any ideas, or experience with this type of code testing?

```
public ABaseClass
{
  protected ThingBaseClass theThing {get;}
  public virtual ....
  ...
}


public AClassUnderTest : ABaseClass
{
  public MyThing Thing
  {
    get
    {
      return (MyThing)base.theThing;
    }
  }

  public void aMethedUnderTest()
  {
    Thing.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Note: The initial value of theThing is null. theThing has no public setter.

Comment: Why can't you check Thnig value? It's just a property of AClass.

Comment: I can check theThing, but not set its value.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create mock that inherits ABaseClass and then check if AClass.Thing returns the same result as ABaseClassMock.theThing

Comment: I think Thing is untestable, but the other methods that use Thing are testable using mocking. Or just using polymorthic inheritance and overriding Thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mocking libraries like Moles. Thus you can set the value of the "thing" from your test code. 
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mock of `ABaseClass` and still set `theThing` using `MOQ` (even though it has no setter)

```
var mock = new Mock<ABaseClass>();
mock.SetupGet(x => x.theThing).Returns(\*Whatever you need*\);
```

Comment: Is there an error in the code in this answer as it looks like it is saying that the class returns something?

Comment: Yes, I updated my typo. It is supposed to say that the property will return something when called